# Get values from an XML object in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I got the following object in PHP:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [native] => France
                )

            [0] => France
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [native] => Nederland
                )

            [0] => Netherlands
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [native] => Deutschland
                )

            [0] => Germany
        )
)
```

How do I get only the values sitting right after `[0]`?
For the given example I would like to have: France Netherlands Germany

Comment: Can you show the XML instead of the SimpleXML objects.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/IVHqE if this can help future answers (but @u_mulder's is good enough).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get **string** value of `SimpleXMLElement Object` cast object to string explicitly:

```
$xmlObject = ...; // your object here
$str = (string) $xmlObject;
echo $str;
// also if you just 
echo $xmlObject;
// $xmlObject will be casted to string implicitly
```

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\start.php on line 122

Comment: Iterate over array, no?

Comment: I would do that if I needed

Comment: @VictorMazilu If you needed...? You posted an array; iterate over it and you can grab each item's text content using the given solution.